# Rails: are there performance implications of single table inheritance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, performance, single-table-inheritance

Using Rails (5.2.3) and Postgres (9.6.6), I'm planning a new model for a large table (~20 million rows and counting, initially).

I'm trying to decide whether to use single table inheritance (STI) or not. Wondering what performance implications there may or may not be.

The rationale for using STI, of course, is that custom logic/methods could be defined in each child class that would pertain only to it.

(Hoping it'll work to use an enum to store integers in the `type` column, for what it's worth.)

Here's how I'm envisioning things with STI:

```rb
class Vehicle < ApplicationRecord
  self.inheritance_column = "make"

  enum make: {
    acura: 0,
    benz: 1,
    # ...
    volvo: 27,
  }

  enum body_style: {
    coupe: 0,
    hatchback: 1,
    sedan: 2,
  }
end

class Acura < Vehicle
end

# get Acura sedans since 2007
Acura.sedan.where("year >= ?", 2007)
```

Here's how I'd envisioning things without STI:

```rb
class Vehicle < ApplicationRecord
  enum make: {
    acura: 0,
    benz: 1,
    # ...
    volvo: 27,
  }

  enum body_style: {
    coupe: 0,
    hatchback: 1,
    sedan: 2,
  }
end

# get Acura sedans since 2007
Vehicle.acura.sedan.where("year >= ?", 2007)
```

**Are these completely equivalent performance-wise? If not, what am I overlooking?**

Comment: You could just look at the generated SQL and ask your DB to explain it if it's different.

Comment: The queries should be the same (assuming that STI won't insist on putting class names in the `make` column). However, STI is (IMO) a horrible thing to do to your database, unnecessarily ties your database to your application, and makes it harder to work with your database without going through ActiveRecord (and sooner or later you'll want to do this if you have a big database).

Comment: This looks like a pretty awful database design. If this is a vehicle registry than you should really be storing car models and the details of each model on a separate table instead of duplicating it all over the place.

Comment: @max: I agree; this is but a toy example standing in for a real case.

Comment: @muistooshort: In the real life case, the model we're wanting to introduce, `TimelineEntry`, will be an aggregation of data from one or two dozen other tables. There'll be a JSONB column to hold the payload we want to feed to the frontend for each `TimelineEntry`. This strategy avoids creating any columns which would have a high percentage of NULLs. The db table would be structured exactly the same whether or not we use STI.